# How does the %(modulus) operator in c works?

Tags: c, modulus

I was trying the following code

```
printf("%d", 010 % 10);
```

I was expecting it output be 0, but it is 8.

Why? Is there any way to get the last digit of an integer which is taken as input.

Comment: `010` is not what you expect, it is an octal number.

Comment: All integer literals starting with`0` are octal (including, a little known fact, zero itself).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any numeric literal in c or c++ starting with a zero will be interpreted as [octal](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/octal-literals-in-c/)

So your calculation is 8 modulo 10, which is 8